# Make og:video play inline whatsapp and facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, youtube, share, facebook-opengraph, whatsapp

Is it possible to add OG:video data to the head of a website so that whatsapp and facebook can play the video inline?
I have currently only seen this working with youtube and instagram links.
Whenever I copy the whole meta data from a working instagram post and paste it into my document the facebook debugger picks up on all the data.
However whatsapp only shows the thumbnail and not the inline video.

Is this feature only for whitelisted domains like youtube or is this something anyone can do?
I noticed that Vimeo also can't play inline video in whatsapp.

This is the meta data and url from Instagram that plays online video in whatsapp.

https://www.instagram.com/p/BtJnyR3lb6o/?utm_source=ig_web_button_share_sheet

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.instagram.com/superjumpbelgium/p/BtJnyR3lb6o/">
    <meta content="112 Likes, 5 Comments - SuperJump (@superjumpbelgium) on Instagram: “How #cool is this &zwj;♀️ #flip #salto #superjump”" name="description">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Instagram">
    <meta property="og:title" content="SuperJump on Instagram: “How #cool is this &zwj;♀️ #flip #salto #superjump”">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://scontent-bru2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/c29fb33d61be461420ca3c97c62c3c63/5C53739C/t51.2885-15/e15/50160334_111325143309745_7951846762696340671_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-bru2-1.cdninstagram.com">
    <meta property="og:description" content="112 Likes, 5 Comments - SuperJump (@superjumpbelgium) on Instagram: “How #cool is this &zwj;♀️ #flip #salto #superjump”">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="124024574287414">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.instagram.com/p/BtJnyR3lb6o/">
    <meta property="instapp:owner_user_id" content="5841998081">
    <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Instagram">
    <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="389801252">
    <meta property="al:ios:url" content="instagram://media?id=1966277691297873576">
    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="Instagram">
    <meta property="al:android:package" content="com.instagram.android">
    <meta property="al:android:url" content="https://www.instagram.com/p/BtJnyR3lb6o/">

    <meta name="medium" content="video">
    <meta property="og:type" content="video">
    <meta property="og:video" content="https://scontent-bru2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/46df451cb72839072bc7ab6078dc3d0f/5C52A4BB/t50.2886-16/51464036_412254452675177_32285228113
```

11104851_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent-bru2-1.cdninstagram.com">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct way to embed a video via OG meta data, but … https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#media:

> Note that your video is not guaranteed to play in-line based on a variety of factors.

A couple of month ago, I heard that Facebook is reducing the number of videos they actually play inline in the news feed. While that note probably refers primarily to that as well, it might be applicable in other apps owned by Facebook, too.

You can’t do more than implement this as outlined in the docs, maybe send it through the Facebook debug tool, too, to make sure there aren’t any errors … but whether it will actually play inline, is out of your hands.