# Video not playing on Facebook when I user og:video tag

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get an S3 video to play in line on Facebook. My site is https://sigtwo.com/vlog/14/.

S3 Video: https://s3.amazonaws.com/spsttestbucket/20190220_142312_NF_2000k.mp4

I believe I used the proper tags as other parts of the post seem to work fine.

Meta tags are as follows:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="SigTwo Mapping & Imagery Solutions" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://sigtwo.com/vlog/14/" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Too many potholes on Storrow Drive after this winter.  Someone needs to fix it." />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://sigtwo.com/static/img/OrangeMaskHeight500.png" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="571517186592163" />
<meta property="og:video:url" content="https://s3.amazonaws.com/spsttestbucket/20190220_142312_NF_2000k.mp4" />     
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="720" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="1280" />
```

Here are results of debugger where everything seems fine:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsigtwo.com%2Fvlog%2F14%2F

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/54423319/10955263

Comment: You can do everything right, but that still doesn’t necessarily mean Facebook will play it inline any more.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I can't do much.